# Import header gives error on Android stuidio

Tags: android, android-studio, asynchttpclient

I am getting cannot resolve symbol 'Header' when I am trying to use AsyncHttpClient.

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post(uploadWebsite, requestParams, new JsonHttpResponseHandler()
{
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response)
  {

  }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse)
{
  super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
  Toast.makeText(OZI_Wishlist.this, "Unable to connect to server. Check your network !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Snapshot of the import issue.
[image]

Can somebody tell me what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to add jar file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add below dependency in your gradle file.

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
```

Because `Header[]` is part of **HttpCore** not **AsyncHttpClient** library..!!

Comment: This worked but strangely I didn't import this part in my previous project and it worked there without this import how is it?

Comment: May be that one is old version of library..If it worked then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `cz.msebera.android` library

Add it to build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

Rebuild/sync and then import to java class:

```
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.*;
```